# Can I change code position of bootstrap Navbar Toggle button?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, optimization, twitter-bootstrap-3

*Hi Guys,*

I want to change code position of bootstrap standard Navbar.

As per my design and code I have 2 Navigation in my Header.
So I need to move that Navbar Toggle icon in my another Navigation, So i need to cut that Toggle code from `<nav> </nav>` tag and paste in my another Navbar code.

***THIS IS STANDARD BOOTSTRAP NAVBAR CODE.***

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

***AND WHAT I NEED IS LIKE BELOW.***

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

     <!--
     // Cut the TOGGLE button
     -->

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="persistent-navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Selling</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Wishlist</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

***Is this ok or wrong please let me know..?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why not?, yes you can use because each Nav have unique ID.**

> I have little modified:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav><div class="persistent-navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="text-left>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-toggle"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <!--<span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> -->
              click here
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Selling</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Wishlist</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool, Thanks mate :)

Comment: Thanks @DynamicDesigner, if the answer is helpful and actually you are looking for this, then mark it accepted.